# Stream from PC to the Raspberry

Tags: kodi, streaming

Is there any way to stream a random media (eg, a video from a random website for which no Kodi plugin exists, or a game running on the PC) to the Raspberry Pi? I'm using Kodi and can't seem to figure this out. Would having Plex Media Server on the PC and a Plex client on the Pi instead help? Can I somehow capture the whole screen and stream it via Nginx or something from the PC to the Pi?

Comment: It is possible to copy files to the Pi remotely using a program called FileZilla. If you want to see a live view of what the Pi is outputting to its hdmi port you can use a program called VNC Viewer, again this can be done wirelessly. What you can do is connect a hard drive to you router and then set up a connection between that and the Pi. Not sure if Plex exists for the Pi

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is DLNA. Install DLNA server on your Pi.

You can then use VLC to stream your main display to the Pi using a DLNA stream.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhvxyiBHrRw
- [Not Pi specific but the same approach You can also use VLC on your PC to stream to DLNA (Pi, TV, Xbox PS4, Plex).](https://superuser.com/questions/447010/how-can-i-stream-a-game-through-vlc-to-my-tv)

Some other considerations....

- I have used [OBS (Open Broadcaster Software)](https://obsproject.com/) - It has a bit of a learning curve to setup but you then stream locally, your Windows/ Mac desktop to a say VLC on the Pi using h264 encodding. Or OMX (since it uses hardware h264 decoding)
- Plex Media server does not support live restreaming, so to speak. I have tried this, and it kind of works with allot of hacks but is terribly slow and laggish.
- I dont really know what Kodi is, but it looks like a Plex type app.
- The Roku3 is really great to stream to. From Plex, VLC, Windows 8, XBOX, Android Miracast.

Comment: kodi is a media cenre os for the raspberry pi, it could be compared to raspbmc check out their page here: http://kodi.tv/. IMO it is the best option you suggested by a long way. You mentioned Roku3, I second that, also there is the amazon fire tv, but the chromecast is cheaper than both

Comment: Yea, I had Chromecast and returned it within 12 hours(Maybe its just me but it was crap). Tried Apple TV, was good for Apple only stuff, XBMC on Pi good but too lagish for me (maybe Pi2 is better now) . Roku is very stable and the only thing that CANNOT connect to it is my iPhone (Except apps like Plex, Youtube, etc), but I am getting rid of that soon (Windows 10 Phone), Android with Miracast is brilliant(but I don't like Android)! Amazon TV... well I don't know really but from reviews its worse than Roku, any Roku. I also didn't want to spend too much but the Roku was a great investment.

Comment: I have Raspberry Pi B+ running XBMC and it can handle MKVs with a bit of overclocking so the Pi2 should have no problems